# set FOSUSERBUNDLE with existing table user (in symfony2)

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I am supposed to built a project with symfony2 for a back end, and angular2 for front end.
For handling user action(authentification,remember me ...) I'am trying to used FOSUSERBUNDLE.
Let me specify that I'am using and existing database which contains a table with many attributes like (id, category, title, name, email, number, adress, ...).   Some of attributes are not the same User in FOSUSERBUNDLE.

My question is how can I set FOSUSERBUNDLE to make it work with my existing  table without brook it?
When I extend my class customer to BaserUser of FOSUserbundle it broke and changed my table structure

below

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class customer extends BaseUser
{



    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="scoring", type="float", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=false)
     */
    private $scoring = '0';

  /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_type", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $idType = '4';

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_categorie", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $idCategorie = '0';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="autorisation_prelevement", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $autorisationPrelevement = 'N';


    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $addresse;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```